# Puppeteer won't start

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

code is hanging on this line, works fine when run as root user

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args:['--no-sandbox']});`

I uninstalled node_modules and reinstalled as the user running the command.

I tried adding the user to sudo

I think its permission issue but not sure what

Comment: Provide your `command ` and `package.json` file.

Comment: @hoangdv same issue even with a node and puppeteer installed only

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by updating node (v12), installing server updates and restarting *sigh